# Start an Hikari Datasource when the DB is not available

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I have configured with Spring a Datasouce with Hkikari to interact with a Maria DB.
Everything is fine if when I start my application the Maria DB is up and running, after the start Hikari is resilient to disconnections and can cope to all the various communication problem.
If the App start when Maria is down the app can't start.

I have configured the Datasource like this:

```java
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(300);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
        hikariConfig.setInitializationFailTimeout(-1);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(3);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(6000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(mariaParams.getPassword());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(mariaParams.getUserName());
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(mariaParams.getUri());
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("MariaHikariPool");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("continue-on-error", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        
        return hikariDataSource;
```

The error I have is:

```
[INFO ] 18:29:30.083 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close() - MariaHikariPool - Shutdown completed.
Aug 29, 2023 6:29:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
[INFO ] 18:29:30.130 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger.logMessage() - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[ERROR] 18:29:30.145 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure() - Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobsInit': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at it.fox.hermes.App.main(App.java:23) [main/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) [spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:313) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at it.fox.hermes.jobs.service.SchedulerJobService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getAllJobList(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at it.fox.hermes.jobs.component.JobsInit.initDefaultJobs(JobsInit.java:20) ~[main/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:783) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: MariaHikariPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 301ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:405) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:378) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy119.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:286) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at it.fox.hermes.jobs.service.SchedulerJobService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getAllJobList(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at it.fox.hermes.jobs.component.JobsInit.initDefaultJobs(JobsInit.java:20) ~[main/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:783) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=maria.farm.rimoldi.it)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connect timed out
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.connectSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:137) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.<init>(StandardClient.java:99) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:70) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:101) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[?:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.connectSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:131) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.<init>(StandardClient.java:99) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:70) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:101) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
2023-08-29 18:29:30 database: closing mem:quartzDb
2023-08-29 18:29:30 database: closed
```

My purpose is to have an app that could start even if the database is not available.
I suspect that some configuration is missing and Kikari infer these information from the database itself when it's seen the first time.

I have tried to change different init parameters but wihthout success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Hikari configuration is fine. It already can achieve what you want to do now which Hikari actually can start successfully in fail safe mode even it cannot connect to DB during startup. But the things are other beans / framework most probably will not support such behaviour during startup and will fail fast immediately. For example, hibernate can only start if the DB can be connected.

In your case , the bean `it.fox.hermes.jobs.component.JobsInit` expect it can connect to DB during start up. So your problem now is more about how to make this bean can start in fail safe mode if the DB is unavailable and can also recover once it finds the DB is available later , more than a problem of configuring Hikari datasouce can start if DB is unavailable which you already can do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the strange thing here is that that bean should work to an another dB which is an in ram embedded H2 and that one it's definitely avaiable! That's wierd. But you are rigth, the problem is somewhere. Thanks